# python - going from a stack trace to a tree

Tags: python, tree, stack, stack-trace

I've been racking my brain for a simple recursive way to do this for a while now - say I have a sequence of states of a stack that looks like this, as a list of lists:

```
[ 
[a]
[a,b]
[a,b,c]
[a,b]
[a,b,d]
[a,b]
[a]
[a,e]
]
```

I want to take this and represent it, essentially as a tree, but using layers of nested lists, without defining a new class for trees.

The tree format of above would probably look something like this

```
[a, [b, [c],
        [d]],
    [e]    ]
```

Essentially, saying that since c and d came after b, they are children of b, and since they have no followers in the stack trace, they have nothing after them (or an empty list to represent no children). So this would also suffice:

```
[a, [b, [c, []],
        [d, []],
    [e, []      ]
```

basically the tree represented is

```
   a
  / \
 e   b
    / \
   c   d
```

But entirely without classes. And yes, I know it's unclean and that a class would probably be the clean way to do that, but I'm interested in the solution for this without classes.

Comment: What code have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here does what you want while putting each node in a list of it's own, which is more readable and usable imho:

```
input =  
[['a'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['a'],
 ['a', 'e']]

output = []
item_node = {}
for lst in input:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] not in item_node:
            item_node[lst[i]] = [lst[i], []]
            if i == 0:
                output.append(item_node[lst[i]])
            else:
                item_node[lst[i-1]][1].append(item_node[lst[i]])

Out[47]: [['a', [['b', [['c', []], ['d', []]]], ['e', []]]]]
```

To get it in the format you wanted first, using the same setup:

```
for lst in input:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] not in item_node:
            item_node[lst[i]] = [lst[i]]
            if i == 0:
                output.append(item_node[lst[i]])
            else:
                item_node[lst[i-1]].append(item_node[lst[i]])


Out[58]: [['a', ['b', ['c'], ['d']], ['e']]]
```

To get your second option:

```
for lst in input:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] not in item_node:
            item_node[lst[i]] = []
            if i == 0:
                output.append(lst[i])
                output.append(item_node[lst[i]])
            else:
                item_node[lst[i-1]].append(lst[i])
                item_node[lst[i-1]].append(item_node[lst[i]])
Out[54]: ['a', ['b', ['c', [], 'd', []], 'e', []]]
```

Comment: Thank you - I think what threw me off was I was entirely conviced I neeeded at least some recursion.